# Webpack Automatically import css from node modules

Tags: css, angularjs, node.js, webpack, node-modules

***TL;DR: Is there any way to automatically scan or automatically import all stylesheets used by our web packages, from our node_modules folder?***

I am working on a project that uses angularJS as its MVC framework, and we are currently in the process of migrating to use webpack. I currently wrote the following configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const bbProperties = require('./webpack.properties');
const appRoot = __dirname + "/../../..";

console.log('__dirname:', __dirname);

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: appRoot + bbProperties.app.entryScript,
        login: appRoot + bbProperties.login.entryScript
    },
    output: {
        path: appRoot +  bbProperties.distFolder,
        publicPath: "dist",
        filename: "js/[name].bundle.js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2017']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                //exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {loader: 'style-loader'},
                    {loader: 'css-loader', query: {importLoaders: 1}},
                    {loader: 'postcss-loader', query: {config: {path: __dirname+'/postcss.config.js'}}}
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name:'[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath:"/assets/images/"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)($|\?.*$)/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name:'[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath:"/assets/fonts/"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            moment: "moment"/*,
            _: "lodash",
            "window._": "lodash",
            angular: "angular"*/
        }),
        //Creates an html file with all bundles injected as <script> tags
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            chunks: ['app'],
            filename: '../angular-app/menu/' + bbProperties.app.outputFile,
            hash: "true", //cache busting
            template: appRoot + bbProperties.app.location + "/" + bbProperties.app.inputFile
        }),
        //Second html bundle for login page
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            chunks: ['login'],
            filename: '../'+bbProperties.login.outputFile,
            hash: "true", //cache busting
            template: appRoot + bbProperties.login.location + "/" + bbProperties.login.inputFile
        })
    ],
    stats: {colors: true},
    devtool: 'source-map',
    node: {
        fs: "empty"
    }
};
```

As far as I understand, webpack will start creating a bundle from each entry file, adding any file it encounters in import statements recursively.

I also understand that I can require a package from my node_modules directory, and that in such a case webpack will search for a package.json file and import the file specified in the 'main' property of that file.

Lets say we are dependant on several packages, components and frameworks (for example: angular-ui-grid, angular-material etc...), I know I can manually import their CSS files using css loaders by importing them into my JS code.

Is there any way to automatically scan or automatically import all stylesheets used by those packages, from our node_modules folder?